# Any tips on moving from ActionScript 3 to Python?

Tags: python, oop, actionscript, migration

I've been developing stuff using ActionScript since AS2,and when AS3 was released i had a bit of a hard time to understand its concepts. Then i realized i had to learn some OOP. I started studying OOP and now i feel i need to take a step further, that's why i chose Python.
Are there any tips/advices/hints or whatever like that to help me on this move?
Thank you in advance.

--edit--
In other words, what are the differences and similarities between the languages?

Comment: Major tip: don't. AS3 is already perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you that I started to understand ActionScript much better after reading [Learning Python](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565924642) and [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) in the meantime